# Make a listbox bigger than default?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just wondering how to make a listbox bigger than the original size it enters as.

It's probably simple but I cant find how to do it.

My code is below:

```
frame_1 = Frame(myGUI)
frame_1.place(x=75, y=300)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_1)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listbox_1 = Listbox(frame_1, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox_1.pack()
scrollbar.config(command=listbox_1.yview)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change it just by setting the appropriate value for `listbox_1`, i.e.:

```
listbox_1['height'] = something
listbox_1['width'] = something_else
```

Or, by using the [config](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.config-method) method:

```
listbox_1.config(width=100, height=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just when you are setting up the list the first time you can set the height and width then.